# ng-class is not being updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cytoscape

```
cy.on('tap', 'edge,:selected', function (event) {
  $scope.$apply(function (response) {

    $scope.dataToDisplay = {
      data1:true
    }

  });
});
```

I have the following code above. It is an event that fires as any edge is clicked/tapped on in a Cytoscape.js graph.

I am able to display the `$scope` object utilizing `$scope.$apply`. In the html, I also have an ng-class directive that will display accordingly whether it's true/false. However, the ng-class does not seem to respond as the value changes.

Below is a snippet of the ng-class directive,

```
<div ng-if="dataToDisplay">
  <div class="panel" ng-class="{'panel-danger': dataToDisplay.data1, 'panel-default': !dataToDisplay.data1}">
  <div>
</div>
```

Assistance is much appreciated.

I would like to clarify that the class does get updated as the page loads. However, I have an additional ng-click event that toggles the true/false. This does not add/remove the class as the value change but the value does get updated in the view. How can I achieve update the class as the value changes?

Comment: Are you sure it's the correct `$scope`? Maybe try rendering `{{ dataToDisplay.data1 }}` just to make sure the value really changes.

Comment: You're using ng-if and with that your ng-class will always have true value. Isn't it? How do you expect it to be updated?

Comment: Please provide me the fiddle.

Comment: @Martin, yup, it's rendering correctly. I can display the value onto the HTML via the curly braces.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Sorry, I don't get you. The ng-if is to display the HTML element of the scope value is defined.